# compiz expo plugin - double-click time

Tags: 14.04, compiz

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Compiz 0.9.11. I configure plugins using CCSM, expo plugin has option Double-Click Time, how it should work ?

Answer (score 0):

The value (time in millisecs) sets how long you may wait between two clicks and compiz would still recognize them as double-clicks.

Example: value=500ms If you click/wait 450ms/click again, you performed a double click. If you waited 550ms instead, compiz would interpret your interaction as two separate clicks.

Comment: If I switch to expo view first mouse click immediately brings me back to the normal view, so I don't understand how it should work together with expo ?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant something else. Did never use expo, sorry :(